# I/O statistics per user

Tags: filesystems, io, nfs, statistics

I have access to an academic supercomputer where there is an NFS filesystem where our lab keeps our data.

When I run `iostats -nh` I believe I am getting statistics for **all** users accessing all storage devices.  Is there a way to see **my own** I/O statistics on this particular NFS filesystem? i.e. see how much of the total load is mine?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. If there is any sort of scheduling manager (such as Moab, SGE, etc.) on the HPC, I would check with the administrators. These scheduling managers have accounting abilities that can give you detailed I/O statistics if configured correctly.

However, those statistics are only useful if all of the I/O to the NFS mount you performed was through the scheduler.

`nfsiostat` unfortunately only reports aggregate statistics for NFS mount points.

Answer (score 1):

[`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) can show which processes are using I/O on a system; it can also be set to show accumulated I/O instead of just bandwidth usage.  It requires Linux kernel 2.6.20 or later. It also needs to be run as root since it uses per process io accounting files in `/proc`.